# Page not found with lowercase description in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and faced a page not found error with description We cannot locate the page you're looking for. Please check the address and make sure all letters are lowercased with no spaces. And my base url is

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost.myproject.com/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Comment: your base url is not correct unless you actually own the domain myproject.com.

Comment: Try with `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

Comment: @caralot it makes no difference if he owns the domain or not. Anyone can create a host file entry and force it to use a different IP address. Then it just depends on the setup of the apache vhosts config. wolfgang1983 that only works in the user has a localhost server setup, there are many different ways to setup testing servers. User101 what is your server setup? Do you use a locally configured http server (apache/nginx etc)? What is your default controller in your routes config? Does this file exist? We are really lacking information that will help understand your actual issue.